# Other data types interaction with own constructed Natural datatype

Tags: haskell, recursive-datastructures

I've made my own data type constructed for the Natural Numbers.

```
data Natural = Zero | Succ Natural 
instance Show Natural where 
         show (Zero) = "0"
         show (Succ Zero) = "S 0"
         show (Succ n) = "S(" ++ show n ++ ")"
```

I'm trying to make a function to interact with basic data types (mostly Int) defined as it follows:

```
intToNat:: Int -> Natural
intToNat 0 = Zero
intToNat n = (Succ n) - 1

natToInt:: Natural -> Int
natToInt Zero = 0
natToInt (Succ n) = 1 + natToInt n
```

Well, this doesn't work at all, the matter is, I must to keep this function as a recursive function. I don't know if the `read` function would be helpful on this.

*UPDATE*: A manner at how the code does compile is using in the function:

```
intToNat:: Int -> Natural
intToNat 0 = Zero
intToNat n = Succ(Succ Zero) --Obviusly this method return a constant number, in this case: 2.
```

So in this case, I guess is related, but I want to know if there is a 'recursive' way to define the 'loop' of `Suc Zero` *n-1* times.

**FINAL Update:** The `intToNat` is defined as it follows:

```
intToNat:: Int -> Natural
intToNat 0 = Zero
intToNat n = Suc(intToNat (n-1))
```

Comment: You don't need to (nor should you) include the answer in your question. If you feel the need to share the solution, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`natToInt` looks OK.  `Zero`, `Succ n`, and `n` all have type `Natural`.  1 and `natToInt n` has type `Int`. You call `+` on two `Int`s.

In `inToNat`, `n` has type `Int`, but `Succ` needs a `Natural`.  You then try to subtract 1 from a `Natural`, but you have not defined `-` for `Natural` (at least, not in the code in your question).  Your `intToNat` is not recursive, but you probably want it to be.

You are generally on the right track.  `read` is not necessary.